# LeetCode: C# fibonacci number iterative solution

Tags: c#, programming-challenge

https://leetcode.com/problems/fibonacci-number/

> The Fibonacci numbers, commonly denoted F(n) form a sequence, called
> the Fibonacci sequence, such that each number is the sum of the two
> preceding ones, starting from 0 and 1. That is,
>
> F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1 F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2), for n > 1. Given n,
> calculate F(n).
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: n = 2 Output: 1 Explanation: F(2) = F(1) + F(0) = 1 + 0 = 1.
> Example 2:
>
> Input: n = 3 Output: 2 Explanation: F(3) = F(2) + F(1) = 1 + 1 = 2.
> Example 3:
>
> Input: n = 4 Output: 3 Explanation: F(4) = F(3) + F(2) = 2 + 1 = 3.
>
> Constraints:
>
> 0 <= n <= 30

here is my solution is there a way to reduce memory foot print?

```
public class Solution {
    public int Fib(int n) {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        int c = 0;
        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) /
        {            
            c = a+b; 
            a = b;       
            b = c;       
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it is coding challenge so naming does not matter, but I think it is a good practice if you try to force yourself to come up with meaningful names even in such program like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can save some memory by getting rid of *i* in for loop and working with input *n*. Although it's not good practice to change input parameters.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = 1;
for(; n > 2; n--)
{            
    c += a; 
    a = b;       
    b = c;       
}
```

I got insteresting results by using .NET 6 and BenchmarkDotNet (I'm not benchmarking/memory expert so take it with a pinch of salt) - for Fib(30):

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Optimized | 14.79 ns | 0.319 ns | 0.283 ns | - | - |
| Original | 25.29 ns | 0.544 ns | 0.994 ns | 0.0153 | 24 B |

Answer (score 2):

The Fibonacci sequence can be written in the form $$\displaystyle \frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}\text{, where}$$ $$\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 1.61803 39887 \cdots$$ $$\text{Is the golden ratio, and}$$ $$\psi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} \approx -0.61803 39887 \cdots$$ $$\text{and since}$$ $$\psi = -\varphi^{-1}$$ $$\text{this formula can be written as}$$ $$\displaystyle F_n = \frac{\varphi^n- \left(-\varphi\right)^{-n}}{2\varphi-1}$$
For example, let n = 15, we would then have
$$\displaystyle \frac{\varphi^{15} - (-\varphi)^{-15}}{2\varphi-1} = 610$$

We can implement this in C# as

```cs
    private static readonly double phi = (1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2;     

    private static readonly double twoPhiMinusOne = 2 * phi - 1;    

    private static int Fib(int n) => Convert.ToInt32((Math.Pow(phi, n) - Math.Pow(-phi, -n)) / twoPhiMinusOne);
```

Which will completely remove the need for a loop.

Comment: This is a nice answer but you should put guard clauses to make sure than `n` is >= 0.  Also, you do not do anything with variable `psi` as it is not referenced in your return expression.

Comment: Pull out some constants so they're not re-calculated every time: `private static readonly double phi = (1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2;
 
private static readonly double twoPhiMinusOne = 2 * phi - 1;
 
private static int Fib(int n) => Convert.ToInt32((Math.Pow(phi, n) - Math.Pow(-phi, -n)) / twoPhiMinusOne);`